# Group and sum data from a list of objects while preserving the insertion order

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have a list of `DijkstraWays` objects:

```
List<DijkstraWays> dijkstraWaysList= ...
```

`DijkstraWays` has the following attributes and getters:

```
class DijkstraWays {
    String name;
    Double cost;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
}
```

I need to group this list by `name` and make the sum of `cost`. For this, I used the following code:

```
Map<String, Double> result = dijkstraWaysList.stream()              
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DijkstraWays::getName, 
                      Collectors.summingDouble(DijkstraWays::getCost)));
```

This code works, but it does not preserve the order of insertion of the elements in `djkstraWaysList` list. This is because `Collectors.groupingBy` returns a Map / HashMap, and this type does not preserve insertion orders.

How can I use `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.summingDouble` preserving the insertion order of the `djkstraWaysList` list? I found several examples on the internet where the result is transformed into a `LinkedHashMap`, which preserves this, but in none of them is it possible to insert the `Collectors.summingDouble`. Example:

```
dijkstraWays.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DijkstraWays::getName,
                                LinkedHashMap::new,
                                Collectors.toList()));
```

I also need the sum of `cost`, but I can't use it together with groupby in these examples with LinkedHashMap.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `Collectors.groupingBy(DijkstraWays::getName, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.summingDouble(DijkstraWays::getCost))`?

Comment: Thanks @ernest_k. This worked perfectly. Code: LinkedHashMap<String, Double> collect = dijkstraWays.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DijkstraWays::getName,
                                 LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.summingDouble(DijkstraWays::getCost)));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Supplier<Map>` for `LinkedHashMap` should be inserted before the downstream collector (in this case `Collectors.summingDouble`) in [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-):

```java
public static Map<String, Double> totalCostGroupByName(List<DijkstraWays> ways) {
    return ways.stream()              
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DijkstraWays::getName,
                    LinkedHashMap::new,
                    Collectors.summingDouble(DijkstraWays::getCost)
            ));
}
```

Test:

```java
List<DijkstraWays> ways = Arrays.asList(
    new DijkstraWays("AB", 3),
    new DijkstraWays("AC", 5),
    new DijkstraWays("AD", 4),
    new DijkstraWays("BC", 3),
    new DijkstraWays("AC", 2),
    new DijkstraWays("AB", 6),
    new DijkstraWays("CD", 10)
);

System.out.println(totalCostGroupByName(ways)); // {AB=9.0, AC=7.0, AD=4.0, BC=3.0, CD=10.0}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. This code worked perfectly, it was exactly what I wanted.